# Is it possible to pass long instead of CORBA::Long etc?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, corba

I cant find the answer anywhere. The quesion is (?) simple. Lets assume I have such function:

```
class Sth {

private:
   long u;
public:
   void set(long u)
   {
    this.u = u;
   }

};
```

and I run it like this:

```
Sth s;
CORBA::Long val = 5;
s.set(val);
```

Can I do this? Will everything be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fine. [According to the IBM reference](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-corbajct3.html#h0), an IDL long is in range of **-2^31 to 2^31-1** and **at least 32 bits** in size.

It should convert natively to `long` in c++. The standard doesn't define a size, but defines the minimum ranges these values can hold. The `CORBA::Long` is a typedef of `long`, which may change between platforms.

Comment: There could be problems when you set values that are outside of the IDL defined range, at that moment they could be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `int_least32_t` (from `<stdint.h>`, or `<cstdint>`), which is a native type guaranteed to be at least 32 bits wide and typedef'd to the appropriate compiler native type.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the inplementation of the IDL to C++ mapping you are using. In the new IDL to C++11 mapping a long in IDL maps to an int32_t.